# Global variable in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API application that is authenticated using a combination of userid and an APIKey as part of the RequestMessage. In my authorization filter I check if the combination is valid before proceeding. I then need to use the userid to log some actions in my controllers.

The UserID and key are encoded together. Something like: .../api/v1/Transaction?api_key=YmFyZGFnYWR2ZXJndXI

The problem I am having is how to expose the userid to the controller.

Comment: What is the source of the userid?

Comment: It's part of the APIKey parameter in the request. The UserID and key are encoded together. 

.../api/v1/Transaction?api_key=YmFyZGFnYWR2ZXJndXI

Comment: @DavidPine Do you have an example for me to follow?

Comment: Can you show your filter?

Comment: About passing data from filter to controller: Implement a public property in your controller (`UserId`) (or one of its base types). In the filter, you can access the controller via the context. If it is of a compatible type, you can just set the property of the controller (e.g. after casting it).

Comment: Side observation: combining `user_id` and `api_key` in one request parameter might be a bad idea. Your request will look better with two params `/api/v1/Transaction?user_id=bob&api_key=YmFyZGFnYWR2ZXJndXI`. This will remove your parsing logic and allow you to easily change `user_id` or `api_key` formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comment from Chips_100 I added CurrentUserId to my Controller and then this code to my AuthFilter:

```
public class CustomAuthFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private BaseController controller;
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {   
        controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as BaseController;
        //Some code ommitted for clarity
        if (controller != null)
            controller.CurrentUserId = userAccount[0];
    }
}
```

Seems to work perfectly so far.